# Accessing WordPress site through alternative domain

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, wordpress

We have several WordPress sites in development. To let our customers take a look at the progress, we had to modify the hosts file of our customer's local machine so far. This isn't the best approach... Another problem: WordPress always redirects calls to the domain set up in the settings, so using an alternative domain (nginx: `server_name`) doesn't work.

So, is there a way in nginx to route all `customer.com` requests to `development.com`?

Example: the customer calls `customer.com`, whose DNS points to the development server. Nginx then routes all requests from `customer.com` to `development.com`, so that WordPress never comes into contact with `customer.com` and the customer only sees `customer.com` in his browser.

Comment: If `customer.com` gets redirected or proxied to `development.com`, it wouldn't be a separate development site anymore, but the content would actually be accessible from `customer.com`. This is a paradox, as arranging it like this would make the arrangement pointless. However, Richard's answer is an actual solution to your problem.

Comment: customer.com is just a temporary domain, not used for production environments. It's just to simplify the access to the site, without the need of editing the hosts file.

Comment: Ok, good. The naming in this question suggests it's the opposite way around. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WordPress uses the HOME and SITEURL variables to determine how to redirect to its own homepage. These are settable in the site's dashboard or the `wp-config.php` file. See [this document](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) for details.

In my experience, this value does not need to contain the scheme or domain name parts of the URL, so `/blog` works perfectly well and allows the site to be accessed using any scheme and any domain name.

*Following testing and comments by OP:*

For sites hosted at `/`, the dashboard will not accept a suitable value, so the `wp-config.php` file must be used. The value should be set to an empty string. The OP also commented that `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` could also be used.

Comment: I'd have recommended settings these variables temporarily to contain the other hostname, but if this really works, it's so much simpler! Thanks for a good answer, Richard.

Comment: Thank you Richard! But there are 2 problems: the WP settings doesn't allow a simple '/' as domain name and setting WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL through wp-config.php the site ends up in ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. Also some media files like images won't work, because they were pasted with an absolute url, instead of a relative path..

Comment: Have you tried using an empty string instead? If you have media links with absolute URLs you will need to edit them, go back to pointing DNS to the test site, or try to rewrite the pages in the reverse proxy (like `sub_filter`).

Comment: Never use absolute URLs within the same site.

Comment: Using empty strings works for the main domain, but leads to ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when pointing another domain to the site.
But there's another solution: using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] for WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL puts the current domain into the settings.

Comment: @EsaJokinen: we never use absolute urls, but some plugins do and we don't have any option to restrict that...

Comment: @greg.ms *ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when pointing another domain to the site* -- this is probably a side-effect from your testing - caused by the browser cache.